# How to flip the sign of a number if two conditions are true?

Tags: math

I am looking for a mathematical expression to flip the sign of a number if two other numbers are positive.

This is easy for a single condition `x > 0`, in which case I'd do `num *= sign(x)`.

But how to do that with two conditions `x > 0` and `y > 0`? This is incorrect:

```
num *= sign(-x) * sign(-y)
```

(as it flips the sign also if both `x < 0` and `y < 0`, which I don't want).

I'd come up with

```
num *= sgn(-x) ** H(y)
```

and

```
num *= 1 - 2 * H(x) * H(y)
```

where `H` is the Heavyside step function, but while that is brief, it's not explicit.

```
num *= (-1)^(H(x) * H(y))
```

is a bit better, but can we go nicer/shorter/more explicit?

This question is not specific to a particular programming language - actually, it's not about programming at all, so using an `if` is not exactly what I want. I am looking for something like an in-line if for mathematicians, and I thought I'd find people with the best mindsets for this question in a programmers' forum... please tell me I was right ;)

Comment: Do you care about zeros, and if so, what do you consider `sign(0)` to be?

Comment: Good point, @MarkDickinson. I haven't found any source where `sign(0)` is NOT `0`, so my solutions up there do not work in all cases; similarly, the Heaviside function seems to be differently defined from author to authors. So yes, I care about 0 in the sense that they should not set `num` to `0` unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: As @MarkDickinson pointed out, you can use `-sign(min(x, y))`:

```
num *= -1 * sign(min(x, y))
```

Then:

- If both are positive - the result is `-1`.
- If at least one of them is negative - the result is `1`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson This would also cover the case where one is negative and the other is positive

Comment: Right: if `x` is postive and `y` is negative, `min(x, y)` is negative, `sign(min(x, y))` is `-1`, so the expression has no effect, as desired.

Comment: With your current answer: if `x` is positive and `y` is negative, `min(x, y)` is negative, and you end up negating: multiplying by `-1 * 1 * -1 * -1`.

Comment: The use of `min` is awesome - that's why I'm here!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation):

> In mathematics, a ternary operation is an n-ary operation with n = 3. A ternary operation on a set A takes any given three elements of A and combines them to form a single element of A. The ternary operator is an operator that takes three arguments. The first argument is a comparison argument, the second is the result upon a true comparison, and the third is the result upon a false comparison.

For example in C++ it would read:

```
num *= (x>0 && y>0) ? -1 : 1;
```

which represents `(condition) ? if_true : if_false`.

This would also work for the special case x and/or y evaluate to 0, since it would not flip the sign. Note [sign(0)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) is usually defined as 0 and that is not the behaviour you said you wanted.